# How do you migrate your dev environment once you get a new laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop

Whenever I get a new laptop, I've to go through the pain of doing a `sudo apt-get install xxx`  of all the stuff I've grown used to, i.e. I've to recreate the entire environment again.
Is there a hassle free way of migrating from one laptop to another, given that I'd use Ubuntu on both of them? (Other than being on a vm all the time? I've also tried physical to vm using Vmware, but hasn't been a smooth an experience)

Comment: +1 have been wondering this as well; what I currently do is put everything I type in the commandline after a new install in a file, and run that file again on a new install. Works pretty well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, to an extent

this assumes that you have the same `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`files the former is for regular repositories, and the latter is where ubuntu adds PPAs to. Copy this off your source system and into your destination system, and run apt-get/aptitude/ubuntu software center's update command - [see this answer on AU for more details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24022/how-can-i-backup-my-repositories)

I've adapted the instructions for tranferring a package list from [ubuntugeek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/clone-your-ubuntu-installation.html).You can dump a list of packages from the source system to a text file called installedpackages with

`sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep '[[:space:]]install$='| awk '{print $1}' > installedpackages`

and copy over installpackages to the destination system then reinstall it with `cat installedpackages | xargs sudo aptitude install` in the location installedpackages is in

Copying over /etc/ may be a good idea as well for major config files.

And of course,copy over `/home/username` in order to get a copy of your working environment, such as your home folders and desktop.

Package list dumping and reinstalling [taken from ubuntugeek.com](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/clone-your-ubuntu-installation.html)

This should cover a good chunk of files on a 'desktop' install of ubuntu. There may be some specific things this would miss (apache virtualhosts comes to mind) but package and desktop related settings should be squared off.

Comment: Thank you @Journeyman Geek ... this looks like the closest thing I'd want to do. 'll go home and give this a try!

Comment: And if you're a PHP/MySQL developer, you should NEVER forget /var/www and /var/lib/mysql. I did once... After that I just changed the default locations of mysql and www to /home/www and /home/mysql - my /home is on a separate partition and it remains unchanged when I reinstall the system or change my computer.

Comment: ahh, yes. Thats part of the issue i guess, I don't know what sort of dev he is ;p. DB other environmental files would need to be moved too.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy whole file systems from one partition to another. E.g. using a combination of `dd` and [`nc`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/netcat).

```
root@old# dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=4M | nc -l -p 4444
root@new# nc old 4444 | dd of=/dev/sda1 bs=4M
```

This assumes that you're running a live system, e.g. from an install CD, on the new system. And that you have a host name or IP address for the old system, so you can connect to it via TCP. `sda1` is assumed to be the partition of the linux file system; adjust as needed if you use a different partition, or multiple partitions. If you can get both drives connected to the same machine, you could use `dd` without `nc`.

After copying the filesystem as stated above, you can

1. Adjust the filesystem size using `resize2fs` in case the new partition is larger.
2. Mount the filesystem somewhere and `chroot` into it to install the bootloader. You might have to `mount --bind` additional filesystems like `/dev` from inside the live system.
3. Again inside the chroot, adjust the set of installed drivers to match the new hardware.

I've migrated my file systems over several different hardware configurations, including several hdds. The switch from 32bit to 64bit was a bit more challenging, but with Gentoo I even managed that without having to reinstall my system from scratch.